# Site migration from Localhost to Server - 404 errors

Tags: 404-error, localhost, ftp

I'm migrating another site from localhost to remote web server and am experiencing an issue. Here are the steps I took:

1.) Downloaded Wordpress locally, and began editing the twentytwelve theme.
2.) Created 8 custom template pages using something like this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/
```

3.) I went to Wordpress dashboard/admin and created 8 pages from the templates I made, then added those pages to the menu bar.
4.) I changed the DB credentials in the wp-config then FTP'd the entire site from localhost to remote host. 
5.) I exported the database and successfully imported onto remote server.
6.) I downloaded the search & replace script and uploaded it to the live server, then ran it and replaced the URLs across the site.

I can now navigate to the home page on the remote host: 
fairchildwebsolutions.com/evo/eco_designs/

However, 404 error displays when I go to any of the other pages I created.

Did I do something wrong? Note that all of the pages display just fine on the localhost.

Thanks

Comment: try to reflush permalinks

Comment: Did you copy over .htaccess?

Comment: @TomJNowell - I'm about 90% positive that I didn't. Should I have done that, or should I not have?

Comment: @Anjum - wow, that worked!! I flushed them from the dashboard and now they are all viewable! Any idea why this happened?

Comment: Yes you should have, and flushing worked because it re-wrote the htaccess =p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some time it's most likely the permalink structure is missing or something went wrong after migration from localhost to live server, the solution is reflush permalink rules to avoid 404 errors.